# JS that Check validation for numbers only including backspace

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create function in JS that Check validation for numbers only including backspace
but the backspace is not working how can I improve the function that the backspace will actually works??

Please Help me.

this is my function :

```
function NumbersOnly(sender, args) {
    var text = sender.get_value() + args.get_keyCharacter();
        if (!text.match('^[0-9]+$'))
        args.set_cancel(true);
    }
```

and I created a RadTextBox in telerik that has ClientEvents for OnKeyPress="NumbersOnly"

Comment: Note that validating keystrokes is not enough, because the user can change the value via the  browser's Edit menu or with drag'n'drop. (And you _are_ validating server-side too, right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isNaN(text) && text != '\b') {
     // code goes here
}
```

you should use keycodes though... it'll make these kind of checks (arguably) easier and (probably) faster, since you'd be checking against the keystroke and not its text equivalent.

BTW isNaN achieves the same result and [can be up to 7 times faster](http://jsfiddle.net/wcgyd). I also find it easier to read than regular expressions.

Comment: now the backspace is working but I can't put any numbers in the textbox do you have any idea why?

Comment: @user2864889 now it should work... remember to mark as answered

Comment: sorry my friend it doesn't work. now I'm trying to insert into the textbox numbers and then delete them by using backspace and seems that it doesn't work :(( I want to allow both functionality to insert numbers and using backspace to delete them and of course not allowing letters what should I need to do??

Comment: what doesn't work, inserting numbers or a backspace? did you change the `||` for a `&&`? it works fine for me... http://jsfiddle.net/WNFb8/

Comment: *test* is more appropriate than *match*: `/^\D+$/.test(text)` also removes the ! operator.

Comment: Err… **isNan** ? :-) Note that this will allow `'1e3'`.

Comment: isNaN, sorry for the typo... While it could allow `'1e3'`, that will never reach the function since OP is binding it to the keypress event (hence the recommendation to use keyCode instead of the string)

Comment: Isn't the code you've shown intended to go inside the keypress event in place of the test the OP had? I don't understand how that would stop `1e3`.

Comment: first you type `1`, and that passes. then you type `e` and that gets blocked (since e by itself isn't a number). Last you type `3`. Again, that passes. The result would be 13, and it's the same result you'd get with both the original regular expression aswell as the one suggested in the comments.

Comment: A simple performance test (http://jsfiddle.net/wcgyd/) shows isNaN to be up to 7 times faster. I also find it easier to read that regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

try this
 (javascript code)

```
function validateNum(event){    
   var allowedChar = "0123456789\b";    
   var keyCode = event.keyCode;    
   var asciiCode = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);                
   if (allowedChar.indexOf(asciiCode) == -1){    
          return false;    
   }    
}
```

(html code)

```
< input type='text' onkeydown='return validateNum(event);'>
```